# Linux, change text field behavior

Tags: linux, gnome, kde-plasma

I have an idea to write a program that modifies the behavior of text fields on Linux. What I want is that the program will automatically change the text entry language according to the textfield's text direction in all the system. For example, if I have English and Hebrew languages installed, and I click on a textfield in some software that normally outputs the text from right to left, than the program will automatically change the text entry language to Hebrew. If I click on a text field that outputs text from left to right, the program will switch the language to English.

I don't know much about system or UI programming on Linux, ( More experienced on Windows ) and I don't know where to start. Is there a way to register 'hooks' on GUI elements on Gnome and KDE? Maybe I should add this to Gnome and KDE's code?

I'd appreciate any hints as to how to start.

Many thanks,

Oded.

Comment: First learn GTK and Qt. Then, specialize their text entry widgets for your wishes. Discuss that on the appropriate Gtk & Qt forum, and propose it. Good luck (you'll need it).

Answer (score 1):

First some caveats:

Normally text field alignment for GUI windowing toolkits is  either explicitly set by the program or is set based on the detected system locale (in Qt and GTK at least) either in relevant Text Object [QLineEdit](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qlineedit.html) in Qt or [GtkEntry](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkEntry.html) in GTK  or in the higher level Layout Object that contains them.

That said in order to implement the functionality at least for your own programs, you will need to identify a few things

- GTK or Qt or both ? If you are implementing at base level (i.e not just bindings), then this also means C or C++ or both ?
- GTK 2 or GTK 3, QT 3 or QT4 ?
- Which text widgets on each GUI toolkit to you want to override ? Just the two I mentioned I above or any or all of the possible text widgets in either library ?
- Do you want your behavior to work regardless of the locale set ? E.g If you have LTR locale set do you want right aligned text widgets to switch input method ?
- What method of switching input method do you want to use ? SCIM, XIM, ibus or just immodule (in both its GTK and Qt forms) ? Do these input methods support being programatically changed ??
- What happens if a user has 2 or more LTR languages installed or 2 more RTL languages installed ? Do they get to pick which language ? Is there current locale setting respected ?

Assuming you want to go down the immodule path

See the following resources for Qt

- [How to support input method in KDE/Qt application.](http://www.kde.gr.jp/~asaki/how-to-support-input-method.html)
- [QInputMethodEvent Class Reference](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qinputmethodevent.html). You will want to implement this event, and the get Text widget's alignment using an alignment accessor, then set the Input Method based on alignment.

See the following resources for GTK

- [GtkIMContext](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkIMContext.html)
- [GtkIMContextSimple](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkIMContextSimple.html)
- [GtkIMMulticontext](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkIMMulticontext.html)

The general method is the same.

1. Implement the event handler for when text is typed into the widget but before it is displayed in the widget.
2. Switch the input method based on the widget's alignment property

Resources on learning GTK

- [GTK 3 Reference Manual](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/)
- [GTK 2 Reference Manual](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/)
- [Gnome Developer Centre](http://developer.gnome.org/)

Resources on learning QT

- [QT Reference Documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/)
- [Qt4 tutorial for absolute beginners](http://sector.ynet.sk/qt4-tutorial/)
- [The Qt4 tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/qt4tutorial/)

From your comment, it seems you would be instead be writing your own InputMethod mechanism or modifying an existing one.

In order to have it loaded by default in Gnome and KDE programs not difficult to do, just set your input method based on locale association. The difficult part is having the InputMethod aware of location it is being typed into. Normally the InputMethod isn't aware of the calling application, let alone the GUI framework it is written in.

Resources on Input Methods

- [List of input methods for UNIX platforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_input_methods_for_UNIX_platforms)
- [Linux input method framework brief summary](http://blogs.gnome.org/happyaron/2011/01/15/linux-input-method-brief-summary/)
- [ibus](http://code.google.com/p/ibus/)
- [uim](http://code.google.com/p/uim/)
- [scim](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/scim/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Comment: Thanks for the directions. It seems I have a lot to learn, but it should be interesting. My idea is not just to implement this on my programs, but to somehow 'hook' into all the textfields in the system, or at least most of them initially. I guess the first step then would be to learn GTK.